# Trying to run a code on all Excel sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to run this code on all worksheets that I have in one excel file but this is not working. It only merges cells on first sheet. Here is my code:

```
Sub MergeColumns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
    Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4"
   ws.Range("H1:S1").Select
            Case Else
    Selection.Merge
        With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    End With
    End Select
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I would appreciate your time regarding the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub MergeColumns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4"
            With ws.Range("H1:S1")
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            End With
        End Select
    Next ws
End Sub
```

or if you want to ignore Sheet1 to Sheet4 then try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub MergeColumns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4"
        Case Else
            With ws.Range("H1:S1")
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            End With
        End Select
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the same operation for ALL sheets(which is right as per my understanding), then, why do you need switch case?

you can just write:

```
Option Explicit
Sub MergeColumns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            With ws.Range("H1:S1")
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```