# Getting My Script To Run Across All Worksheets (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

This code works on one sheet **and now am trying get it to work across multiple sheets, avoiding the first two sheets ("AA" and "Word Frequency")**.

Original code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845719/categorize-each-string-under-group-1-time-based-on-string-content-excel) (See @Jeeped's answer)

Link to Worksheet [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByUcHTNcynugQUt3TWJ2ZzVnZHM/view?usp=sharing)

Was trying to adapt code from related threads I found (Reference [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194224/macro-to-run-through-all-worksheets-with-one-exception), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288400/trying-to-run-a-code-on-all-excel-sheets)) however I do not know how (and whether) to apply the `Ws.Name` and `Ws.Range` objects into my existing code.

It seems like the code activates Sheet1 using `With Worksheets("Sheet1")` and I was trying to replace this with the following method:

1. Create `For` looped function *byGroupCounter()* to identify how many worksheets there are, and run across all existing worksheets. Each worksheet will be incremented with variable "i"
2. `For` loop in *byGroupCounter()* calls on function *byGroup(i)* to run the original code on the selected worksheet (ie. worksheet "*i*")
3. The *byGroup()* function runs it's process across worksheet *i*.
4. **Part where I believe I'm getting an error:** Replacing the `With Worksheets("Sheet1")` code to `With Ws`, where `Ws = Worksheets(Sheet_Index)` and *Sheet_Index* is equal to *i*, defined from `byGroupCounter()`

I believe I have to add the `Ws` prefix in front of `.Range` but everything I've been trying, I keep getting the error "Can't execute code in break mode".

Current Code:

```
Sub byGroupCounter()

  Dim i As Integer

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = ActiveSheet.Index To Sheets.Count
  byGroup i
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub byGroup(ByVal Sheets_Index As Integer)
  Dim g As Long, s As Long, aSTRs As Variant, aGRPs As Variant
  Dim Ws As Worksheet
  Set Ws = Worksheets(Sheet_Index)

appTGGL bTGGL:=False

' I believe the next line is where I am doing something wrong:
With Ws
    aSTRs = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value2
    With .Range(.Cells(1, 5), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0,        Application.Match("zzz", .Rows(1)) - 1))
        .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
        aGRPs = Ws.Cells.Value2
    End With

    For s = LBound(aSTRs, 1) To UBound(aSTRs, 1)
        For g = LBound(aGRPs, 2) To UBound(aGRPs, 2)
            If CBool(InStr(1, aSTRs(s, 1), aGRPs(1, g), vbTextCompare)) Then
                aGRPs(s + 1, g) = aSTRs(s, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next g
    Next s

    .Cells(1, 5).Resize(UBound(aGRPs, 1), UBound(aGRPs, 2)) = aGRPs

  End With

  appTGGL
End Sub

Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    Debug.Print Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
    Application.EnableEvents = bTGGL
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
    Application.Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic,     xlCalculationManual)
End Sub
```

Comment: You should not use Sheet.Index when you want to skip by Worksheet.Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are just 6 changes to the original code to loop through the sheets

I have them commented with '<<<

```
Sub byGroup()
    Dim g As Long, s As Long, aSTRs As Variant, aGRPs As Variant, sh As Worksheet    '<<<

    appTGGL bTGGL:=False
    For Each sh In Sheets    '<<<
        If sh.Name <> "AA" And sh.Name <> "Word Frequency" Then    '<<<<
            With sh    '<<<
                aSTRs = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value2
                With .Range(.Cells(1, 5), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, Application.Match("zzz", .Rows(1)) - 1))
                    .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
                    aGRPs = .Cells.Value2
                End With

                For s = LBound(aSTRs, 1) To UBound(aSTRs, 1)
                    For g = LBound(aGRPs, 2) To UBound(aGRPs, 2)
                        If CBool(InStr(1, aSTRs(s, 1), aGRPs(1, g), vbTextCompare)) Then
                            aGRPs(s + 1, g) = aSTRs(s, 1)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next g
                Next s

                .Cells(1, 5).Resize(UBound(aGRPs, 1), UBound(aGRPs, 2)) = aGRPs

            End With
        End If    '<<<<
    Next sh    '<<<
    appTGGL
End Sub

Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    Debug.Print Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
    Application.EnableEvents = bTGGL
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
    Application.Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
End Sub
```

Comment: Forgot to add code to skip `AA` and `Word Frequency` worksheets?

Comment: Edited to avoid Sheets "AA" and "Word Frequency"

Comment: Works great, thank you! Also many thanks for the comments, it's great to finally understand how I can use the same loop with the 'For Each sh in Sheets' and 'With sh'... wasn't sure about the structure but this makes it very clear